# Read a letter not read by the user in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My application has a collection called: Letters

These cards are read by users.

I need to create a query that refers only to a letter that was not read by the authenticated user.

Already tried:

```
letters
   users
          uid: true
          uid: true
          uid: false
```

It works however I will have to create references "users" for all created letters and each creation of a user, not counting that the maximum number of fields in a map is 20.

I thought about having:

```
letters /${userId}.read
```

However I will always have to create the reference for each letter to the user.

Obtain from the card collection a card that has not been read by that UID

Answer (score 0):

How about if you add an array to each new letter called `read`, and every time a new user reads the letter you add their id to the array. Then you can use an `array_contains id` query to check if a user has read it before.